# Disable _notes folder that Dreamweaver as a IDE

Tags: dreamweaver

I use Adobe Dreamweaver as an IDE...I know the horror.  It has worked well for many years and in code view.  I don't need the power of Eclipse or have a mac so anyway the latest release has so non-funtioning settings on my pc.

I disable Maintain Sync Settings and clean up design notes, but they keep coming back.

Any one have any thoughts why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable both "Maintain Synchronization Information" and "Maintain Design Notes". See some guidance [here](http://www.webworkgarage.com/2014/01/how-to-make-dreamweaver-not-add-a-_notes-folder-in-the-various-directories-of-your-website/).